# Python functions to move all files and folders to a destination folder

Tags: python, file, directory

I have a txt file, in which in each line i have the path of files and folders i want to segregate into one place.

The list is something like this in my list.txt file.
Each entry starts off on a new line.

```
 C:\xxx\xxy
 C:\abc\def\ghi.pdf
```

and my destination folder is c:\users\mr_a\dest

**I want to :**

**1. move the directory `xxy` and all its files and subfolders to `dest`**

**2. move `ghi.pdf` file to `dest`.**

Do the same for other entries in the `list.txt` file.
So that my `dest` directory would look like:

```
dest\xxy
dest\ghi.pdf
```

I looked into `shutil` but am not still sure which function to use.
It says that the `destination` directory shouldn't be already existing, but in my case its not so. I'm getting confused which methods to use.
Please also mention if the methods you mention are safe (I don't want any nasty cut-n-paste where bits of my files may go missing etc)

*What I'm asking is: What methods to use to accomplish what I need to do here?*

Edit: And I use Windows, not Linux or any Unix system

Comment: i went through `shutil` docs in which frankly i couldn't make up my mind about which methods to use. That's why I'm asking here.

Comment: should think that a simple os.walk coupled with os.path.isdir and os.mkdir should do the trick

Comment: A call to `shutil.move` and a container to keep track of the shallowest dirs should do

Answer (score 0):

```
with open('list.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        shutil.move(line, dest)
```

Comment: But would it merge the directory dir in case of: dest/dir/a.txt src/dir/b.txt? I believe that's one part of the problem for @ronnieaka

Answer (score 0):

Check out `os` and `os.path`. You will find some useful functions like:

- `os.path.exists` - checks whether a path exist (like your destination path)
- `os.makedirs` - creates a directory (including missing parent directory)
- `os.path.isdir`, `os.path.isfile` - checks whether the path contains a directory or a file.
- `os.path.basename` - cuts the filename out of a path
- `os.path.join` - joins paths (or a path with a filename)

Here is a code example, I didn't try it:

```
if not os.path.exists(dest):
    os.makedirs(dest)
with open('list.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
         filepath = line.strip()
         filename = os.path.basename(filepath)
         shutil.move(filepath, os.path.join(dest, filename))
```

Comment: Just `shutil.move(filepath.strip(), dest)`
did it. thank you. 
Only major change i had to make was to add strip() otherwise i was getting `IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('rb') or filename: 'C:\\\\Python27\\\\b\n'` 

And i had to replace all single backslashes with double backslashes in the `dest` variable.
`dest =  "C:\Python27\a"` gave : 

`File "C:\Python27\my\batchmove.py", line 5, in <module>
    os.makedirs(dest)
...
WindowsError: [Error 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: 'C:\\Python27\x07'`